# hide array of objects based on route variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have below array of route objects having structure below, i am trying to hide menu option `Construction` and all submenu's under that menu option with the bool variable

```
const libraryRoutes = ({ isAuth }) => ({
  title: 'Library',
  icon: <BookOutlined />,
  homePath: '/library',
  children: [
   {
     .......
   },
   { isDevelopmentMode &&  {   // at here i am getting syntax error 
      type: 'subMenu',
      title: 'Construction',
      icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/library/construction-material-type',
          exact: true,
          title: 'Construction Material Type',
          icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,              
        },
        {
          path: '/library/construction-set',
          exact: true,
          title: 'Construction Set',
          icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,            
        }
      ]
    }},
    {
      .......
    }
  ]
});
```

I am getting syntax error as shown in above code, could any one please let me know how to hide based on routes variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your ternary condition in `()`. Else you can build your object outside of the returned value as follow :

```
const libraryRoutes = ({ isAuth }) => {
  const routesForDev = () => {
    if (!isDevelopmentMode){
      return {};
    }

    return {   
      type: 'subMenu',
      title: 'Construction',
      icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/library/construction-material-type',
          exact: true,
          title: 'Construction Material Type',
          icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,              
        },
        {
          path: '/library/construction-set',
          exact: true,
          title: 'Construction Set',
          icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,            
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  
  return {
    title: 'Library',
    icon: <BookOutlined />,
    homePath: '/library',
    children: [
      {
        .......
      },
      routesForDev(),
      {
        .......
      }
    ]
  }
};
```